# What are the FNV_1a parameters for a 16-bit hash?

Tags: algorithm, hash

The offset basis and prime number for the [FNV-1a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) hash function are given by [various](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function#FNV_hash_parameters) [sources](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/#FNV-param) for hash lengths starting at 32 bits.

But I can't find these numbers given for a 16-bit hash. Does anyone know a trustworthy source for values for these parameters? (Or, is there some reason why they're not given, e.g. why a 16-bit hash doesn't make sense?)

[This page](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/#FNV-param) gives code for computing the offset basis for a given hash size, so I've implemented that in Python, and came up with 40389. But I'd like to confirm that with an authoritative source.

[The same source](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/#fnv-prime) gives a specification (not an algorithm) for the FNV prime for a given hash size. Finding that prime is not as easy, and not a wheel I want to reinvent if I can find it lying around somewhere.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't compute FNV-1a 32bit and truncate it to 16?  And yes, there are lots of reasons such small hash functions aren't usually defined.  The probability for collisions is far too high to be useful in most cases.

Comment: I could compute FNV-1a 32bit and truncate it to 16. Maybe that's the best answer. But the same could be asked, why not compute FNV-1a 64bit and truncate it to 32 when you need 32 bits? I'm guessing the answer is performance. Which may not matter so much for the 16 bit case.

Comment: Or maybe the answer is that most hardware today optimizes for 32- or 64-bit arithmetic and bitwise operations, so 32-bit parameter values are useful for 32-bit CPUs, but there are practically no 16-bit CPUs nowadays.

Comment: In the "Changing the FNV hash size - xor-folding" section of the page you reference it says: "To produce a 16 bit FNV-1 hash in C we xor-fold fold a 32 bit FNV-1 hash:" together with some C code.  That is presumably the official way to produce a 16-bit FNV hash.

Comment: @rossum Thanks, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/ there is no 16-bit FNV hash that makes sense.

Their recommendation instead is therefore to do a 32-bit hash with xor-folding.  That is you xor the first 16 bits with the last 16 bits.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that. Disappointing, because I'm trying to implement the hash in an environment that has no XOR as such. But that's a separate issue. :-)